# P-test for Improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to see if this integral converges or not, so we have $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}$$
Using P-Test I know if $1+\frac{1}{x}>1$, then this integral converges, but could the $x$ be negative so $1+\frac{1}{x}<1$?? then the integral diverges?
Thanks

Comment: Does this improper integral converge or diverge? any ideas?

Comment: You have defined your integral over the region $x>1$ so no it cannot be negative

Answer (score 4):

The integral has form $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) dx$, where $\frac{1}{f(x)} = x \cdot x^{\frac{1}{x}} = x \cdot e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}} = x \cdot e^{\bar{o}(1)} \sim x$. Hence $f(x) \sim \frac1{x}$. It's well known that $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac1{x} dx$ diverges. So the intergal $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ diverges also.

Comment: In fact, for $x\ge 1$ $$\frac1{x^{1+1/x}}\ge \frac1{e^{1/e}x}$$